# connectOrCreate in createMany prisma query?

Tags: prisma

Currently we are mass uploading a lot of Entries of a model that are related to another model. We are currently using create (singular) to connect the entry to the other model one at a time. Is there a way to do this with createMany?

We are using postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Nested relations in `createMany` is not supported at the moment.

Here's the feature request for the same:

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5455

You can loop over your records and use `create` with `connectOrCreate`.